# Difference between the barcode fonts and other barcode libraries

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know the difference between the barcode fonts and other barcode libraries that are available.

1. How does these fonts work?
2. I mean how does it differ from other barcode libraries?can these barcode fonts be used for commercial purpose too?
3. Is it feasible enough to use in commercial applications?
4. There are some third party barcode libraries.
5. how do i see from their dll or lib file that which are libraries they have used.

Difference between free barcode fonts and other barcode libraries?

Answer (score 3):

1. Since each barcode is a representation of a string, and each character in the string is represented exactly by a segment of a barcode, each character of the barcode string may be represented individually. Because of this, you can represent a barcode using a font (although barcodes such as EAN13 require a prefix and suffix, but these can be represented by a character as well).
   The font simply draws a set of lines instead of drawing a `4`, for example.
2. The other way of rendering barcodes is by drawing lines manually, which may produce the same output. Scaling of the barcode would have to be done manually as well. By using fonts you get the best result when printing a barcode though.
3. Using fonts usually provides the best result detail-wise, especially when printing. I can't think of a limitation that would make them not suitable for commercial applications. The ability to display barcodes in office applications is a nice bonus.
4. I don't know of any libraries, sofar I've used fonts or rendered my own.
5. If it's a .NET assembly you can use ILSpy to view contents / dependencies of the assembly if the library was merged into the main assembly, otherwise the dll will be in the folder of the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would like to render my own barcodes.I mean drawing each line manually. This way i can learn a lot more.But where do i start from?If I am going for creating my own,i would have to create a lib or dll file and how do i do that? When it comes to using barcode fonts,Certain symbologies require check digit calculation like code128,upc etc and there it plays a major drawback in using the barcode fonts i guess.

Comment: I have used net reflector to view the dll files and its very complex to understand what libraries they have used and the flow too.

Comment: The dll's you viewed are probably obfuscated then, I wouldn't spend time trying to decode them. Regarding check digits - you'll have to calculate them regardless of whether you are using fonts or rendering your own. The check digits are easy to calculate though and part of the 'character data' rendered using a font.

Comment: In your comment you ask how to create a dll, I suggest following some general tutorials on writing a dll and using them in your application, before diving deep into the barcode details.

Comment: yes I have taken a small step by first learning to create a simple dll for now. I directly don't want to jump in barcode dll.But I would like to know the libraries i.e namespaces that would be needed to create my own barcode library.I want to list down those libraries.can you please help me out?

Comment: One way of representing barcodes is by drawing on a bitmap, which is explained here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Bitmaps_for_Persistent_Graphics_in_C_Sharp if you later decide to go printing you can reuse the code to draw the barcode, because the printer also uses the `Graphics` object.

Comment: But bitmap consumes more space.it may cause resolution degradation.how do i implement vector based generators?

Comment: This is far beyond your initial question. I suggest you ask how to draw vector-based images in a separate question as I am no expert on that subject, and the experts aren't watching this thread as the question is regarding fonts and barcodes.

Comment: yup thank you. its already been asked in a separate thread. Actually I have started creating lines manually.But drawing the lines similar to barcode I am feeling it a bit difficult.